# Cookiee set in PHP; but not being found?

Tags: php, session, cookies, isset

When a user logs in, here is my user function:

```
public function login($user) {
    global $database;
    if ($user) {

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id;
        $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

        $_SESSION['username'] = $user->username;
        $this->username = $_SESSION['username'];

        setcookie('user_id', $this->user_id, time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 14));
        setcookie('username', $this->username, time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 14));

        $this->logged_in = true;

    }
}
```

When I look at the Cookiees in Chrome, I find two cookies relating to this:
1 for user_id, 1 for username.

But when the browser is closed and I try to come back, it will not detect the cookiee:  Here is the process:

```
class Session {

     // Most of the class has been edited out; the code above is also a method in this clas. Removed so it's not duplicated.


     private $logged_in = false;
     public $user_id; // yes I realize this is insecure
     public $username; // yes I realize this is insecure

     function __construct() {
          session_start();
           $this->check_login();
     }

    public function is_logged_in() {
        return $this->logged_in;
    }

   private function check_login() {

    if (isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) && (isset($_COOKIE['username']))) {
        $_SESSION['user_id']= $_COOKIE['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];

    } else { // When I test, below shows up showing it doesn't think Cookie is set.
        echo "Cookie not set in check_login().<br />";
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $this->username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $this->logged_in = true;
    } else {
        unset($this->user_id);
        $this->logged_in = false;

    }
  }

 $session = new Session();

}
```

Comment: What does `print_r($_COOKIE);` print on the 1) next load after setting the cookie and 2) after closing and reopening the browser?

Comment: After I log in, it shows the correct cookie name and value. This:  [user_id] => 1 [username] => Joe User.  It also shows the PHPSESSID and a couple of Google Analytic cookies.  When I reopen the browser.  It only shows the Google cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the path and domain.

```
setcookie('user_id', $this->user_id, time() + 3600, '/', '.yourdomain.com');
```

If you leave the path to empty, the cookie will only "active" within the current directory. For example, if your login script is `http://example.com/user/login.php`, then when you open `http://example.com`, the browser won't set the cookies.

Comment: Question:  My login set the cookie in .domain/folder/HERE.  The page that the browser opens up to is one directory back:  .domain/HERE -- so which path do I use?

Comment: I just figured it out.  '/' makes it available for the whole domain.  I then had to update my log out script to make it match and it all works perfectly!